# How to add a default function key with ARM template for a deployment slot in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-function-app

I want to add a default function key to my deployment slot in azure.  Therefore I've added it to my template like this:

```json
...,
{
   "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/functions/keys",
   "dependsOn":[
     "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', variables('apiServiceName'),'deploy')]"
   ],
   "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
   "name": "[concat(variables('apiServiceName'),'/deploy/default/eventgrid')]",
   "properties": {
       "name": "eventgrid"
   }
},...
```

Unfortunately, I cannot find how to get it to work, this is the closest I can find to not have the template fail (fewer segments make the template invalid)
Now I get this error:

> NotFound: Error creating or updating function key.

The API docs explain how it works, and I think it matches what I have here for the ARM template, but I can't seem to figure out why I get a not found error...
Anyone ever tried this for an azure function slot?
I can get it to work for the production slot though:

```json
...,
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
    "dependsOn":[
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', variables('apiServiceName'))]"
    ],
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[concat(variables('apiServiceName'), '/default/eventgrid')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "event-grid"
    }
},...
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to add default key using ARM templates? Actually, it would be created automatically after you create your slot.

Comment: I mean a non-function specific key, I name it eventgrid but it is default, so across all functions... because at time of deployment the functions might not be published there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. I think you're missing the slot name in the name property:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/host/functionKeys",
    "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
    "name": "[concat(variables('functionAppName'), '/staging', '/default/key')]",
    "properties": {
        "name": "key",
        "value": "[parameters('key')]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', variables('functionAppName'), 'staging')]"
    ]
},
```

Comment: Yes, you are right... the documentation wasn't complete there as it was referring to /sites/slots/functions/keys when in fact it was /sites/slots/hosts/functionKeys... I got Microsoft support to look at it with me, and by inspecting in more detail and trying the rest calls I figured it out... (and forgot to update this question)... thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't yet comment, so I am force to write an answer :-( I would like to add one small thing that I found super helpful when using the above answer. I expect that someone looking at this question might find it helpful to see this linked directly here.

While trying to deploy multiple environments with one ARM template I used the above answer and extended it by creating one parameter per environment in the parameter file:

```
"parameters": {
        "subscription": {
            "value": "<mySub>"
        },
        "env": {
            "value": "<env>"
        },
        "devHostKey": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                  "id": "/subscriptions/<mySubID>/resourceGroups/<myKvRG>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KvName>"
              },
              "secretName": "<KeyName>"
            }
        },
        "accHostKey": { .... },
        "prdHostKey": {..... }
    }
```

Then in my ARM template I used

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "subscription": {
      "type": "string"
     },
    "env": {
      "type": "string"
     },
    "devHostKey": {
      "type": "securestring"
     },
    "accHostKey": {
      "type": "securestring"
     },
    "prdHostKey": {
      "type": "securestring"
     }
  },
  "resources":[
    {"type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots/host/functionKeys",
      "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
      "name": "[concat(variables('func_name'),'/', variables('slot_name') ,'/default/default')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "default",
        "value": "[if(equals(parameters('env'),'dev'),parameters('devHostKey'),if(equals(parameters('env'),'acc'),parameters('accHostKey'),parameters('prdHostKey')))]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/slots', variables('func_name'),variables('slot_name'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

This way I can deploy this slot *default* slot Host key to all my environments just by changing the "env" parameter in my parameter file, and then rerunning the script.

Hope this helps someone in the future :-)